# Does Stream Analytics support output to SQL Server memory optimized table?

Tags: sql-server, azure-stream-analytics, memory-optimized-tables

In the book **"Mastering Azure Analytics: Architecting in the Cloud"** by Zoiner Tejada I found a paragraph stating that memory optimized tables are not yet supported as output by Stream Analytics.

[Source to Book Link](https://books.google.at/books?id=hCKeDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA383&lpg=PA383&dq=stream%20analytics%20output%20to%20memory%20optimized%20table&source=bl&ots=eE47Kf-g-U&sig=p4RerXs3SYSGsKLKJQsWybO95nQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwihlYDbtp3UAhUNL1AKHSTCBN0Q6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=memory%20optimized%20table&f=false)

As books are not very good in catching up with those dynamic cloud offerings my question is: does this restriction still apply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use memory optimized table from Azure SQL Database as ASA ouput.

Thanks,

JS - Azure Stream Analytics team.

Answer (score 1):

I agree, you can use in-memory tables as outputs for ASA. The only problem is that you may experience primary key or unique contraint violations errors due to the guarantee of at least once delivery (https://msdn.microsoft.com/azure/stream-analytics/reference/event-delivery-guarantees-azure-stream-analytics).